# Stop MySQL table backticks from preventing cross schema queries

Tags: mysql

I've noticed weird behavior in MySQL, cross schema queries are only possible if the `{schema}.{table_name}` isn't quoted in backticks`` (`) ``. Now this is technically defined behavior according to the MySQL's technique to escape reserved words being used as tablenames etc., however it seems counter intuitive that one feature (safely using reserved words) prevents another feature (cross schema queries). Is there some way to disable this or is my only option to just not use backticks around my tablenames in cross schema queries.

Comment: Are you putting backticks around the whole thing instead of the separate components `\`schema\`.\`table\``?

Comment: I wasn't doing anything per say, an ORM was generating these invalid ````schema table```` name combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema name and the table name are individual tokens, and should be delimited separately.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html says:

> If any components of a multiple-part name require quoting, quote them individually rather than quoting the name as a whole. For example, write `my-table`.`my-column`, not `my-table.my-column`.

The same applies when using schemas and tables, for example:

WRONG — tries to find a table whose name is literally `db1.mytable` in the current schema.

```
SELECT * FROM `db1.mytable`;
```

RIGHT — uses the qualified table named `mytable` in the schema `db1`.

```
SELECT * FROM `db1`.`mytable`;
```

Comment: Thank you, not really a MySQL user was helping someone figure out a problem with their codebase and an ORM was generating these invalid whole backticked table names.

Comment: It's possible the ORM wasn't designed to format qualified table names properly. Lots of ORM packages are designed by programmers who wish their database were simpler than it is in fact.

Comment: I mean the ORM had an intentional change schema option that would update the models query to switch schemas. Forked it and removed the bit that backticked table names as a workaround 

Comment: This may causes issues with JSON path.