# Sequelize - Unknown column in 'where clause'" when trying to filter by included model

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to implement search functionality in a Sequelize query. Here is the query itself:

```
const sites = await Site.findAndCountAll({
        order,
        limit: limits.limit,
        offset: limits.offset,
        where,
        include: [
            {
                model: Account,
                attributes: ['account_id', 'name', 'customer_id'],
                paranoid: false,
                required: true,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: Customer,
                        attributes: ['customer_id', 'name'],
                        paranoid: false,
                        required: true,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                model: Version,
                as: 'versions',
                limit: 1,
                order: [['version_id', 'desc']],
                attributes: ['status', 'config', 'user_id', 'updated_at', 'version_id', 'updated_by', 'is_prod'],
                include: [
                    {
                        model: User,
                        as: 'updatedByUser',
                        attributes: ['email'],
                        paranoid: false,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                model: SiteService,
                attributes: ['service'],
                paranoid: false,
                required: true,
            }
        ],
        distinct: true,
    });
```

The `where` clause includes several things, but this is how searching is implemented:

```
if (search) {
    where[Op.or] = [
        { domain: { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` } },
        { '$Account.name$': { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` } },
        { '$Account.Customer.name$': { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` } },
        { '$SiteService.service$': { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` } },
    ];
}
```

So as you can see, it's searching by multiple values, namely the site domain, account name, customer name, and service. The only one that's failing is the `SiteService` search, with this removed the search works for domain, account and customer. The services are also fetched fine from the related table if no search term is present, but if I include a search term, the query fails with the message

```
sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'SiteService.service' in 'where clause'",
```

I don't understand why this same approach is working for the other included models but not for `SiteService`. `Site` and `SiteService` have the following associations:

```
Site.hasMany(models.SiteService, {
    foreignKey: 'site_id',
});
```

```
SiteService.belongsTo(models.Site, {
    foreignKey: 'site_id',
});
```

I've managed to get the desired behavior by using a raw SQL query, however at this point I'm curious why the seemingly same approach works in some places and not in others. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**
I'm adding the SQL that gets generated by Sequelize here:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(`Site`.`site_id`)) AS `count` 
FROM `sites` AS `Site` 
INNER JOIN `accounts` AS `Account` 
  ON `Site`.`account_id` = `Account`.`account_id` 
INNER JOIN `customers` AS `Account->Customer` 
  ON `Account`.`customer_id` = `Account->Customer`.`customer_id` 
INNER JOIN `site_services` AS `SiteServices` 
  ON `Site`.`site_id` = `SiteServices`.`site_id` 
WHERE (
  `Site`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
  AND (
    (`Site`.`domain` LIKE '%test%' 
    OR `Account`.`name` LIKE '%test%' 
    OR `Account->Customer`.`name` LIKE '%test%' 
    OR `SiteService`.`service` LIKE '%test%') 
  AND `Site`.`is_active` = 1));"
```

Comment: I'd guess it's trying to delimite `SiteService.service` as though it's one identifier, not a qualified identifier. See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72454405/stop-mysql-table-backticks-from-preventing-cross-schema-queries/72454429#72454429 But it's hard to tell because we're reading code that generates SQL, instead of reading the SQL it generates.

Comment: @BillKarwin I'm getting the SQL that Sequelize outputs when it errors and I'll update the question with it, please take a look and let me know if anything looks off, frankly I'm no SQL expert.

Comment: Seems like you need to indicate `$SiteServices.service$`

Answer (score 1):

I see a difference in the spelling of the table alias:

```
INNER JOIN `site_services` AS `SiteServices` 
...
OR `SiteService`.`service` LIKE ...
```

If you define the alias as `SiteServices`, you must use that alias with the 's' at the end.

Is Sequelize doing automatic pluralizing when it forms the table alias? I'm not a regular user of Sequelize, but I see this in the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#table-name-inference):

> By default, when the table name is not given, Sequelize automatically pluralizes the model name and uses that as the table name.

The documentation shows how to disable automatic pluralization.

Or you could follow the pluralization, and use `SiteServices` instead of `SiteService` where appropriate.

Comment: I haven't actually defined any aliases directly, so this is Sequelize trying to be clever I guess. I've tried using the plural form now but that just gets me to `sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'SiteServices.service' in 'where clause'",`, so even pluralized I have the same issue. 
This seems like a good lead though, as it does look like Sequelize is doing some things I don't want it to. I'll do some more digging. Thank you!

Comment: This is the tricky part of using ORM tools — they try to be too clever, and you end up spending more time debugging by examining the SQL generated by the ORM anyway. You might have been better off sticking with the direct approach and using a raw query.

Comment: Sequelize offers a handy way to run raw queries, doing the following results in exactly the behavior I want from this:
```Sequelize.literal(`EXISTS (SELECT * FROM site_services WHERE site_services.site_id = Site.site_id AND site_services.service LIKE '%${search}%')`),```
This is how I'll probably keep it in the end, this whole question is mainly fuelled by my curiosity about why it doesn't work rather than **having** to use this approach.